# R Shiny - Setting input values with 'session$sendCustomMessage' inside a Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny

My app contains a button called `set value`. I would like to use `sendCustomMessage` and `setInputValue` to reset the value of input `inp` to 'hi' each time `set value` is clicked. I'm using a wrapper function called `setInputVal` for the `sendCustomMessage` method.

The value of `inp` is reset as expected if I specify the namespace prefix for the input id inside the call to setInputVal but not if I leave it out. So `setInputVal(session, ns('inp'), 'hi')` works but `setInputVal(session, 'inp', 'hi')` doesn't.

**Why do I need to specify the namespace prefix here?** My thinking was that the `session$` bit in `session$sendCustomMessage` implies that the message is accessing module's session and so the namespace prefix isn't be required (similar to how in the module's server function we use `input$inp` to access `inp`'s value and not `input[[ns('inp')]]`).

**And why is it that when we use an `update*` function (like `updateSelectInput`) in a module server, we don't need to specify the ns prefix?** (I've included a `selectInput` in the UI and an observeEvent in the server to demonstrate `updateSelectInput`.) When I look at the code for updateSelectInput, I see that it also uses `session$sendInputMessage(inputId, message)` and does not seem to attach the ns prefix to the inputId parameter at any point.

```
library(shiny)

setInputVal <- function(session, inputId, value) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(
    type = 'setInputVal',
    message = list(
      id = inputId, value = value)
  )
}

# module UI ---------------------------------------------------------------
modUI <- function(id) {

  ns = NS(id)

  tagList(
    tags$head(tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('setInputVal', function(data) {
  Shiny.setInputValue(data.id, data.value);
});")),
    # selectInput(ns('letter'), 'letter', letters),
    actionButton(ns('set'), 'set value')
  )
}


# module server -----------------------------------------------------------
modServer <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns = session$ns

  observeEvent(input$set, setInputVal(session, 'inp', value = 'hi'))

  observe(print(input$inp))

  # observeEvent(input$set, {
  #   
  #   updateSelectInput(session, 'letter', selected = 'u')
  #   
  #   print(input$letter)
  # })
}


# main UI -----------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(modUI('hi'))


# main server -------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  callModule(modServer, 'hi')
}

# Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Where does `useShinyUtils()` come from?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sendCustomMessage()` you are just sending a JSON object to be handled in JavaScript. By the time you call `Shiny.setInputValue()` in JS, you've already lost all information about the session: only the message data remains. And in this case that message happens to contain an unscoped input id, meaning that you're actually setting the value for a global `"inp"` input. Because a custom message could literally be doing anything, there's nothing that the session can modify about it.

However, when you use `sendInputMessage()` the context is different: now the session knows that there is an `inputId` and it should be scoped, which it does automatically; see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/d04a9902350a70a19a32ff37dfb04e9f6a635706/R/shiny.R#L748-L750).

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't noticed that it was using `sendInputMessage` and not `sendCustomMessage`. And I would only be able to use `sendInputMessage` for an input that exists in the DOM? It doesn't seem to do anything for the input in my app since that input doesn't exist in the UI.

Comment: @user51462 yeah I noticed that, too, when testing this. I think that's because if the input doesn't exist in the DOM, Shiny doesn't really know anything about it; for example, there isn't information anywhere that this input should be a text input. I suspect that this situation is pretty similar to having [a custom input object](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-inputs.html) and as such might require some manual input bindings? But I'm not certain about that.